# NullPointerException reading from file using Scanner in Android?

Tags: java, android, file, java.util.scanner

I have a file of Geoid values, and I am trying to read it. I have tried commenting some code, then test and found out that the NullPointerException occurred in the readFile() method and I have no idea why.

Geoid.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

public class Geoid extends Activity{

    Scanner openGeoid;

    String[] geoidStr = new String[1040000];
    double[] geoid = new double[1040000];

    double lat;
    double longi;
    int geoidIndex;

    public void getLatLong(double latIn, double longIn){
        lat = (-(Math.round(latIn * 4) / 4 + 90) + 180) * 4;
        if(longIn >= 0){
            longi = (Math.round(longIn * 4) / 4) * 4;
        }
        if(longIn < 0){
            longi = (Math.round(longIn * 4) / 4 + 360) * 4;
        }
    }

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            openGeoid = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.geoid));
        }catch(Exception e){
            ;
        }
    }

    public double readFile(){

        for(int c = 0;openGeoid.hasNext();c++){     
            geoidStr[c] = openGeoid.next();
            geoid[c] = Double.parseDouble(geoidStr[c]);     
        }   

        geoidIndex = (int)Math.round(lat * 1441 + longi);
        return geoid[geoidIndex];

    }

    public void closeFile(){    
        openGeoid.close();  
    }
}
```

getOffSet method of MainActivity.java:

```
 public double getOffSet(double lat, double longi){

        Geoid geo = new Geoid();
        geo.getLatLong(lat, longi);
        geo.openFile();
        double offset = geo.readFile();
        geo.closeFile();
        return offset;

    }
```

Comment: What line throws the NPE?

Comment: @Vakh should be the first line

Comment: you must be calling readFile before openfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Geoid geo = new Geoid();
```

you should never use the `new` operator to instantiate an `Activity`, because the `Activity` follows its own life cycle and, getResources is available after the `Activity`'s  onStart is called, and onStart is called if you actually started your `Activity` through an `Intent`. If you need an Activity just for the sake of `getResources` add an additional parameter to the method's signature. A `Context` object, for instance

Comment: How to create that Context object

Comment: you don't have to create a Context's object. Activity inherits from Context, so if you start the activity correctly, after onStart, you have already a valid instance of Context

Comment: I see. Actually that Geoid.java was originally meant for a Java class instead of an activity. I extended Activity because of the getResource(), as you have mentioned. How do I read from geoid.txt without the need to create an Activity, or you need an activity? @blackbelt

Comment: you have to if you want to use `R.raw`. By the way, your application should have a least one activity or a service

Comment: may I ask you why are you allocating two arrays of `1040000` ? Of course it is not related to your issue. It is just curiosity

Comment: This Geoid file covers the entire planet at 0.25 degree intervals @blackbelt

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an exception occurred in the `openFile` method so the `openGeoid` variable does not get instanciated.

In `openFile`, you should not catch exceptions without doing anything.

Comment: I also thought that was what happened @Vakh